# Docker Ruby 2.6.6-alpine is twice as big as Ruby-2.6.5-alpine

Tags: ruby, docker, alpine-linux

Docker image using ruby-2.6.6-alpine creates a 498mb image size. However, when I downgrade to ruby-2.6.5-alpine, it goes back to 266mb. The 2.6.6 release is almost twice as big. Why is this so?

```
# RESULTS IN 266MB
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        build-base \
        postgresql-dev \
        vim \
        tzdata \
        bash \
        less

# RESULTS IN 498MB
FROM ruby:2.6.6-alpine
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        build-base \
        postgresql-dev \
        vim \
        tzdata \
        bash \
        less
```

Comment: I have edited the answer with more analysis: `postgresql-dev` seems to be the culprit here.

Comment: I have edited the answer with a possible workaround, and a 305Mo image size based on `ruby-2.6.6-alpine`, only 40Mo bigger than based on `ruby-2.6.5-alpine`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TLDR; replace `postgresql-dev` with `'postgresql-dev<12.2-r0'`

As in:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
...\
'postgresql-dev<12.2-r0'\
...
```

You will get (with `ruby:2.6.6-alpine` as base image) a 305Mo image size, close enough of the 265Mo you have when the base image is `ruby:2.6.5-alpine`.

---

Details:

I don't seem to make [`imagelayers.io`](https://imagelayers.io/) work properly, so I fall back to [`wagoodman/dive`](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to inspect layers of those two images.

In both case, I get images of 50Mo (49.5 for 2.6.5-alpine)

[image: base image]

So the base image is not a problem here.

The difference is:

Your dependency list will install, when done from 2.6.6, the following *additional* packages:

```
{+Installing xz-libs (5.2.5-r0)+}
{+Installing libxml2 (2.9.10-r4)+}
{+Installing llvm10-libs (10.0.0-r2)+}
{+Installing clang-libs (10.0.0-r2)+}
{+Installing clang (10.0.0-r2)+}
{+Installing llvm10 (10.0.0-r2)+}
{+Installing icu-libs (67.1-r0)+}
{+Installing icu (67.1-r0)+}
{+Installing icu-dev (67.1-r0)+}
```

That is due to the difference between:

- [docker ruby 2.6.6 alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/8e49e25b591d4cfa6324b6dada4f16629a1e51ce/2.6/alpine3.12/Dockerfile) based on `alpine:3.12`
- [docker ruby 2.6.5 alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/defb10adcd6dd2178be3cd9c884fd035b52d42fb/2.6/alpine3.11/Dockerfile) based on alpine 3.11 (or 3.9)

I added [this gist](https://gist.github.com/meetmatt/d5dd2ecae37fbabb483dffba2d6dbec6) to your Dockerfile

```
RUN apk info | xargs -n1 -I{} apk info -s {} | xargs -n4 | awk '{print $4,$1}' | sort -rn
```

I see

```
85360640 gcc-9.2.0-r4
```

vs.

```
109056000 gcc-9.3.0-r2
63430656 llvm10-libs-10.0.0-r2
62976000 clang-libs-10.0.0-r2
```

- `gcc` is bigger (from 85Mo to 109)
- `llvm10-libs` and `clang-libs` adds 125Mo

As illustrated in "[The Quest for Minimal Docker Images, part 2](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2020/03/01/quest-minimal-docker-images-part-2/)" from **[Jérôme Petazzoni](https://twitter.com/jpetazzo)**, it is best to use a **[multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)** like:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add build-base
COPY hello.c .
RUN gcc -o hello hello.c

FROM alpine
COPY --from=0 hello .
CMD ["./hello"]
```

---

Notes, looking for the size increase root cause:

- [`build_base` for Alpine 3.9](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/ppc64le/build-base) has 7 dependencies
- [`build_base` for Alpine 3.11](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/main/armhf/build-base) has 7 dependencies
- [build_base for Alpine 3.12](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/build-base) has 8.

The additional dependency is [`patch`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/patch), which itself depends on [`musl`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/musl): very small.
The size issue is not related to `build-base`

Let's change your `Dockerfile` to:

```
RUN apk add --update
RUN apk info build-base
RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache vim
RUN apk add --update --no-cache tzdata
RUN apk add --update --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --update --no-cache less
```

The utility `dive` will show `postgresql-dev` is the one needing `clang` with Alpine 3.12.

- [`postgresql-dev` for Alpine 3.11](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/main/x86_64/postgresql-dev) has 5 dependencies
- [`postgresql-dev` for Alpine 3.12](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/postgresql-dev) has 8

Those three additional dependencies are:

- [`clang`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/clang) (25Mo)
- [`icu-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/icu-dev)
- [`llvm10`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/llvm10) (which itself depends on [`llvm10-libs`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/llvm10-libs), 60Mo)

From [Alpine 3.10+ to 3.12](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?firstlist=alpine&secondlist=alpine&secondversions=0&resource=compare-packages&firstversions=1), installing `postgresql` means embarking `clang`, but the difference in size for `postgresql-dev` is *massive* between the two.

- Alpine 3.11 or lower: 15Mo for `postgresql-dev`

[image: Alpine 3.11 postgresq-dev]

- Alpine 3.12: *215Mo* for `postgresql-dev`

[image: Alpine 3.12 postgresql-dev]

That is because of a recent change in dependencies for the [Alpine postgresql `APKBUILD`](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/blame/master/main/postgresql/APKBUILD).
See:

- [commit f040d3a](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/commit/f040d3a3a9a4bb0b727e3c2e133340cdb22bab98) from [**Jakub Jirutka**](https://github.com/jirutka) adding `clang` and `llvm`.
- [commit 2bf48a5](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/commit/2bf48a5fa3e6ce3d1cfcd25f4df3df7801a60b89) from [**Ariadne Conill**](https://github.com/kaniini) adding `icu-dev`.

The comment of the first commit mentions:

> Since we build PostgreSQL with JIT support enabled, `clang` and `llvm-lto` are required for building extensions with PGXS.

Probably because of [`docker-library/postgres` issue 475](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/475): "JIT `--with-llvm`"

... which leads to [`docker-library/postgres` issue 651](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/651): "**postgres:12.0-alpine upgrade to postgres:12.1-alpine double size**".

See "[Postgresql 12: What Is JIT compilation?](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/jit-reason.html)"

> Just-in-Time (JIT) compilation is the process of turning some form of interpreted program evaluation into a native program, and doing so at run time.
>
> For example, instead of using general-purpose code that can evaluate arbitrary SQL expressions to evaluate a particular SQL predicate like `WHERE a.col = 3`, it is possible to generate a function that is specific to that expression and can be natively executed by the CPU, yielding a speedup.
>
> PostgreSQL has builtin support to perform JIT compilation using LLVM when PostgreSQL is built with `--with-llvm`.

All that [because now](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/just-upgrade-how-postgresql-12-can-improve-your-performance):

> For PostgreSQL 12 systems that support [LLVM](https://llvm.org/), just-in-time compilation, aka "JIT," is enabled by default.

This is reflected in [how postgresql is built for Docker](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/commit/b1f60bd4f88fa2f82aaaa304dc1476a26938cb38): see [commit c8bf23b](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/commit/c8bf23b75fa75a99eef9f5ff794c557057e5d8c5) from [issue 643](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/643), and merged in [`docker-library/official-images` PR 7042](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/7042).

So... possible workaround: limit the version of `postgresql-dev`, as explained in "[How to install a specific package version in Alpine?](https://superuser.com/a/1058665/141)":

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache 'postgresql-dev<12.2-r0'
```

That will make sure to use the 15Mo `postgresql` instead of the 215Mo one.

Comment: Interesting. Like what you recommended, I've gotten around this issue by using multi-stage builds. Although this significant size increase still seems like a big gotcha for anyone upgrading to the latest ruby 2.6 alpine series version. 

Thanks for taking the time in analyzing the docker image, would definitely use the dive tool in analyzing my docker images in the future.

Comment: Darn JIT for postgresql (see my edited answer above). And the benefits don't seem always obvious: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264955/handling-performance-problems-with-jit-in-postgres-12, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20191204194332.eurzkwkqhlsbbd73%40alap3.anarazel.de#7ad68b5036e931c640f385a34d4fdbed. See also https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-just-time-compilation-jit-postgresql

Comment: And... you cannot force the removal of the extra depencies: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475226/alpine-how-to-forcibly-remove-a-package-even-if-it-would-break-dependencies: "`the following packages are not removed due to:  llvm10: postgresql-dev`"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Seems bizarre for postgres to enable JIT by default. I 
recently upgraded an RDS instance from 11 to 12, and I noticed a considerable slower performance in some of my queries. The answer was tweaking the default JIT parameter. Who knew this issue was related!